# How do I use Jade to control content inside a script block?

Tags: pug

Say I have a Jade like this:

```
script.
  var city = "#{city_name}";
  var state = "#{state_name}";
```

However, I want to remove the whole second line: `var state = "#{state_name}";` if `city_name` equals `Washington DC`.

How do I write that `if-else` pair in Jade?

I want something like this:

```
script.
  var city = "#{city_name}";
  {if city_name != "Washington DC"}
    var state = "#{state_name}";
```

My current solution not so perfect:

```
script.
  var city = "#{city_name}";
if (city_name != "Washington DC")
  script.
    var state = "#{state_name}";
```

It would work, but it brings an extra blank `script`.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it very simple with dot blocks:

```
script
    .
        var city = "#{city_name}";
    if(city_name != 'Washington DC')
        .
            var state = "#{state_name}";
```